# pentaho reporting: postprocessing script for scatter chart to display limit (static value) on axis

Tags: charts

[image: ScatterPlot with limit intersection]

I have a requirement to generate Scatterplot chart with limits on x and y axis as in the attached image on Pentaho Report Designer.
As there is no option available under scatter plot to display the limit line, I am trying to implement through Post Processing script in chart. But not able to achieve.
Kindly help to achieve the above requirement in Pentaho Report Designer charts.

Comment: could you please share what you've already tried?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I do not have good knowledge on scripting. I need help to get the desired output. Below is the script i tried, but this will connect the dots to create a line:                                                             

        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
        XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
        renderer.setSeriesLinesVisible(0, true);
        plot.setRenderer(renderer);
        return chart;

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you draw a line. Scripting language used is Groovy.

```
import org.jfree.chart.plot.ValueMarker;

def marker = new ValueMarker(100);
def plot = chart.getPlot();
plot.addDomainMarker(marker);
```

Comment: Defined the Groovy script as shared above in Scatter XY Collector.prpt under SampleReports->Charts>Scatter report in pentaho report designer, but Marker is not visible on chart. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: script worked fine! Thanks for the help :)  I am looking on formatting options like Line colour, bold and dotted. I tried with the below script:  import org.jfree.chart.plot.ValueMarker;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
def marker = new ValueMarker(5.5);
def marker1 = new ValueMarker(15000);
def plot = chart.getPlot();
plot.addDomainMarker(marker);
plot.addRangeMarker(marker1);

XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
renderer.setBasePaint(Color.blue);
renderer.setBaseFillPaint(Color.blue);
plot.setRenderer(renderer);

Comment: Hi Egor Zhuk, could you please help me how to add label for Domain marker 'SDR Limit' as in the above image.

Comment: @Pratyusha yes, please read the jfree charts tutorial and documentation

Comment: Thanks, i am able to implement the formatting. Please let me know if the "markedPoints": 1,2,3.....16 is possible to achieve on the plot with Datapoints? as in the above screenshot